# How many different answer keys are possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A professor writes $40$ discrete mathematics true/false questions. Of the statements in these questions, $17$ are true. If the questions can be positioned in any order, how many different answer keys are possible?

Comment: How many ways are there to choose $17$ of the $40$ positions in the order?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Lets start by considering the order in which the 17 true statement is picked as being important,  How many ways can you pick the true statements?  Clue there are 40 ways to pick the first, 39 the second, etc.  But the order doesn't matter so how many ways can you order 17 items? What do you think you need to do with these two numbers?

Answer (score -1):

No. of questions=40. so, 40! ways of arrangements.
No. of ways of arranging answers= 2^40( two choices true and false)
total no. of keys possible= 40!*2^40

Comment: You did not take into account the fact that precisely $17$ of the $40$ statements are true.